# what type do you give an object with children in a typescript interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, interface, typescript-typings

I have a response

```
filereader.onload = function(evt: any) {
  url = evt.target.result; //sending the link to url
};
```

But considering the fact that removing type any makes the application faster.
I tried giving the vet parameter the type of object but then the property target did not exist on type object.
I also tried using an interface but giving it any still brings the same issue I am trying to get rid of.

Comment: Types don't make the application faster or slower. They don't exist when the ts code is transpiled to javascript.

Comment: If onload is typed, Typescript should infer the type, IOW just remove the :any

Comment: You can use the [Event interface](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.event.html): `function(evt: Event): void { ... }`

Comment: After doing this                                                                                    
filereader.onload = function(evt: Event) {
      url = evt.target.result; //sending the link to url
    }; the evt.target.result throws an error Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Answer (score 0):

The following inline type should do the trick:

```
filereader.onload = function(evt: { target: { result: string } }) {
  url = evt.target.result; //sending the link to url
};
```